# Toggling Layers using CartoDB

Tags: google-maps, kml, carto, google, kmz

Does anyone have ideas or know how one might be able to use CartoDB to create a map that one can toggle the individual features within a KML file, as currently happens on [this map](https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=http://www.orenstransitpage.com/otpisraelpics/jlembusmap/jerusalembusmap.kmz&ie=UTF8&ll=31.771229,35.203629&spn=0.067716,0.154324&z=13&output=classic&dg=feature)?

I want my users to be able to toggle individual routes on and off, and Google is removing the feature that allows the KML/KMZ files to be overlaid on Google Maps in February.

I already have a barebones setup based off some other research I've done, but was hoping that maybe there is a more robust solution out there that is closer to what I have right now.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout [this tutorial](http://docs.cartodb.com/tutorials/toggle_map_view.html).  It looks like you have tons of layers so you would need to change the position of the buttons, but I think if you upload each route as an indivudal table then combine them into one single visualization it would work.  Or you could add it in as a single table and then use SQL filters to display the chosen routes possibly.